# Strange warnings when using my array class

Tags: c++, arrays, g++, compiler-warnings, gcc-warning

I've written a pretty simple array class in C++ and use it in my application:

```
/* A simple array class template that performs dynamic */
/* memory management and casting to (T*), which allows */
/* to use it as a usual array. */
template <typename T>
class Array
{
public:
    //Constructor
    Array(unsigned long size)
    {
        try
        {
            data = new T[size];
            m_size = size;
        }
        catch(...)
        {
            cout << "Could not allocate " << size << " bytes." << endl;
            data = NULL; m_size = 0;
        }
    }
    //Typecast operator
    operator T*() { assert(data!=NULL); return data; }
    //Subscript operator
    T& operator[] (unsigned long Index);
    //Destructor
    ~Array() { if(data!=NULL) delete[] data; }
private:
    T * data;
    unsigned long m_size;
};

template<typename T>
T& Array<T>::operator[] (unsigned long Index)
{
    assert(Index<m_size);
    assert(data!=NULL);
    return data[Index];
}
```

However, when I use it like this:

```
Array<char> filename(5);
filename[0] = SomeVar;
```

GCC ouputs the following warning:

```
warning: ISO C++ says that these are ambiguous, even though the worst conversion for the first is better than the worst conversion for the second: [enabled by default]
note: candidate 1: T& Array<T>::operator[](long unsigned int) [with T = char]
note: candidate 2: operator[](char*, int) <built-in>
```

What is the reason? How can I solve it?

Comment: Stating GCC version and warning flags would've been nice, since my GCC 4.8.4 doesn't complain. But Petr nailed it already, so all is good.

Comment: GCC 4.8.1 in MinGW, -Wall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is quite simple: for your `filename[0]` the compiler can use your `operator[]`, or it can convert `filename` to `char*` using your type conversion operator, and then apply `operator[]` to a `char` pointer.

More explicitly, what happening is

```
filename.Array<char>::operator[](0)
```

vs

```
filename.Array<char>::operator char*().operator[](0)
```

(don't know whether the latter is correct c++, but it gives an idea of what happening)

P.S. Almost sure this should have been asked before, but was not able to find a duplicate.

Comment: `operator T*() { assert(data!=NULL); return data; }` seems to be the reversed conversion of  constructor `Array( T * p){ data = p};`?

Comment: Oh, I see! Can I remove the subscipt operator?

Comment: @Ilya use explicit conversion operators. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading?rq=1)

Comment: @Ilya It seems that by `operator T*() { assert(data!=NULL); return data; }` is to convert a `Array<T>` to `T*`, and by  `Array( T * p){ data = p;}` is a `T*` to a `Array<T>`. And use `explicit` would prevent the implicit conversion.

Comment: No, operator T* returns Array.data, and I don't see where you have found the Array(T* p) constructor.

Comment: And even if it existed, what's the problem?